# Can i get DirectoryInfo from FTP Server without FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, directory-structure, ftpwebrequest, directoryinfo

I was answering a Question about how to show a directory structure on FTP Server, therefor it was needed to use System.IO.DirectoryInfo[].

Is there any easier way to get **DirectoryInfo[]** from ftp Server than using FtpWebRequest and Response as in [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2004/09/15/230177.aspx)?

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't do that. DirectoryInfo only works on the local filesystem (and local network shares)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not what you need but you can write a small Class which returns a Directoryinfo Object